# IK Not Rendering 2.8

Tags: rendering, animation

I am currently using Blender 2.81 Alpha and I like to try out something new with Blender's latest version. I have created my own rig with working armatures and constraints. I have rendered animations on 2.79 in the past and it works properly but rendering on 2.80. Half of the rigs especially IK doesn't animate while rendering except view port.

Working in Viewport
https://i.imgur.com/Gs34157.gif

Not working in Render CYCLE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBslY.gif

The only why I can make the rigs to move by reducing influence but it doesn't help on the head, hands and forearm.

Keeping the influence 100 percent on each rig makes three rigs complete 100 percent still like a rooster!

Comment: I finally have the right arm moving except the left arm is still frozen while rendering..

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)